# Instancing Vertices Light sources

Tags: vertices, lighting, instances

So I'm trying to rotate a bunch of lights around a large circle using using the instancing vertices, so each lamp is on a vertex[image]

But when I rotate the circle, the lights rotate around the "top" lamp, and ignore the others
[image]

The lights will move with the vertices along each axis, they just rotate wrong.
So I need to know if there's a way to fix it, and how to do it, cause I am stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just use an object and make the lamp child of the object. Then instance that object (which you can make invisible afterwards). if this does not help, please provide blend file

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I’ve figured it out. Once I made the instance, it wouldn’t rotate around the center.
So I went to the ‘object’ menu
‘Apply’
‘Make instances real’
And now the instances rotate around the center point.